# How to pass a dataframe from jinja to flask route

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I have a jinja template that displays a dataframe and I would like to pass this dataframe through a form to a new route in flask.

In the HTML form, I tried the following code but with no success:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dataname" value={{dataframe|safe}}>
```

Can anyone suggest the best possible way to pass a data frame to the flask route?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but maybe you can JSON-encode the dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mark's suggestion, I did the following:

In jinja, I converted the data frame to JSON as follows:

`{%set json_dataframe = dataframe.to_json()%}`

html code for passing the datframe to flask route:

```
<input type="hidden" name="dataname" value={{json_dataframe}}>
```

and in the flask route, I loaded the json dictionary as:

```
parsed_json = json.loads(json_dataframe)
```

and then converted to a data frame using:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed_json)
```

That's it. This worked like a charm!